# Do I need an Australian visa if I have a British visa?

Tags: visas, uk, australia, new-zealand

I will be traveling to New Zealand and Australia with a cruise ship. Do I need an Australian entry visa and New Zealand entry visa if I already have a UK multiple entry visa?

Comment: Australia gained independence of the United Kingdom 117 years ago. Just FYI.

Comment: What passport do you have?

Comment: Not if your passport is visa-free. But a UK visa does not eempt you from an Australian or New Zeland one, no

Comment: Depending on what exactly you count as determining "independence", dates as late as 1986 could be argued for. But both Australia and New Zealand are certainly separate countries _today_, and run their own visa regimes.

Comment: @chx The Governor General, being the representative of the Australian Monarch, residing in Australia might beg to differ with you.

Comment: @PeterM The Queen is the regent of Australia independently of her role as regent of the UK.  The same applies to Canada.  The UK government has absolutely no control, theoretical or otherwise, over the government of either country, except through the use of its military.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie technically yes, but the highest poetical office in Australia is Prime Minister and the Prime Minister can only form a government at the pleasure of the GG.  Just ask Gough.  That is not what I would call independent.

Comment: @PeterM The governor general represents the Queen of Australia, not the Queen of the United Kingdom.  If the United Kingdom abolished its monarchy, Australia could retain its monarchy.

Comment: @phoog Yet the ultimate political control of Australia currently rests in a person who is not a citizen of Australia nor resides in Australia, but in fact is a citizen of the UK and resides there.

Comment: @PeterM the irony of which is particularly ripe at the moment given the recent wave of resignations of Australian MPs with dual nationality.  I'm not sure that the queen is a citizen of the UK, though, since she is the personification of the state itself.  The same is presumably true in Australia.

Comment: @phoog The Queen does not even have a passport.  As regent, she does not require one, and legally, she is a citizen of all the states where she is regent.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I know that she doesn't have a passport.  Some web searching indicates that some constitutional scholars suggest that she is not a citizen of the state because she is the state.  In the days before British citizenship, the question was much clearer with respect to the UK: she certainly was not a British subject after her father died, because how could she be a subject of herself? I've also read that she is *not* an Australian citizen, but cannot find a reference supporting that at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

A UK visa is not valid outside the UK, so **yes**, you will need visas for both Australia and New Zealand if you plan on disembarking the cruise ship.

Australia, in particular, requires basically everybody except Kiwis to get visas, although for most visitors they can easily by obtained online. New Zealand's visa policy is somewhat more liberal.

Comment: Also note in very broad and generic terms that while some residency/long-term visas might allow you to skip a short term visa (especially transit visas) elsewhere, I never heard of an independent country accepting another's visitor visa.

Comment: @chx El Salvador allows visa-free entry to Dominican citizens holding US, Canadian or Schengen visas but otherwise requires a visa. As I recall, quite a few Central American and Caribbean countries allow US/Canadian/Schengen visa holders to enter without getting another visa

Comment: In general true but some UK visitor visas are recognised in Ireland, and vice versa, for Indian and Chinese citizens.